# Create a temporary to pass to rvalue reference

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I want to code several recursively interacting merge functions, which I think should have signatures:  `T&& merge_XYZ(T&& a, T&& b);`

They will tend to be used recursively with lines such as:

```
return merge_XYZ( std::move(x), std::move(y) );
```

Each of these several merge functions will steal the contents of one of the inputs and inject those contents into the other input and return the result.  Typically, they will have `x` and `y` which are names for what were rvalue references and thus should be converted back to rvalue references by `std::move` (correct me if I'm wrong).

But rarely, they have `x` and or `y` that are references to objects whose contents must not be stolen.  I definitely don't want to write alternate non stealing versions of these functions.  Rather, I want the caller to deal with that in these rare cases.  So my main question is whether the correct way to do that is to explicitly invoke copy construction, such as:

```
T temp = merge_QRS( T(x), T(y) ); // use x and y without stealing yet
return merge_XYZ( merge_MNO( std::move(x), std::move(y) ), std::move(temp) );
```

Main question:  Is `T(x)` the right way to force a temporary copy to be created at that point?

Other questions:
Is `T temp =` the correct way to make sure the call to `merge_QRS` in the above code occurs before the call to `merge_MNO` but otherwise inexpensively forward the temporary from that into the first operand of `merge_XYZ`?  If I used `T&& temp` instead does it end up holding a pointer to modified `T(x)` after the life of `T(x)`?

Is `T&&` the right return type (as opposed to `T`) for chaining a lot of these together?

How does the above compare to:

```
T tx = x;
T&& temp = merge_QRS( std::move(tx), T(y) ); // use x and y without stealing yet
return merge_XYZ( merge_MNO( std::move(x), std::move(y) ), std::move(temp) );
```

Assuming `merge_QRS` will be modifying tx and returning an rvalue reference to that, is that behavior all defined?

Writing this question may have helped me realize I could be mixing together two situations that ought not to be mixed:  Object you don't want to steal from vs. objects you don't want to steal from **yet**.  Is my original `merge_QRS( T(y), T(x))` right (only if consumed within the same expression) for objects I don't want to steal from?  But in the case I tried as an example should I have the following:

```
T tx = x;  // Make copies which can be stolen from
T ty = y;
return merge_XYZ( merge_MNO( std::move(x), std::move(y) ),
                  merge_QRS( std::move(tx), std::move(ty) ) );
```

I think I may still be confused about stealing the contents vs. stealing the identity.  If I return by `T&&` I'm stealing the identity of one input in addition to stealing the contents of the other.  When do I get away with stealing an identity?  If I return by `T` I'm never stealing an identity, and sometimes failing to steal an identity is inefficient.

Comment: If you don't want an object to be "stolen from" when passed as parameter either don't pass it as a parameter or rely on the fact that lvalues don't bind to rvalue references ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e05851d887896a53))

Comment: @MarcoA.  I don't want a compile time error.  I want correctly working code.  (Actually I do want a compile time error when I incorrectly pass an object to a stealing function.  I think my design covers that.  But I want a correct way to pass those, meaning a way to make a copy for the purpose of having that copy stolen from).

Comment: How about defining `T&& merge_XYZ(T a, T b)` ? Would that work? With no move() it would create a temp, and with move() it would call && version.

Comment: @Arkadiy, I think that expands into three extra versions of each of several functions:  `(T a, T&&b)` `(T&&a, T b)` etc. each forwarding to the real one.  Then if I make a call incorrectly, I silently get the inefficient version instead of a compile time error telling me what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Does your T have a move constructor? If so, then you may as well always pass by value and let T::T(T&&) take care of it.

Comment: My head hurts. I guess I'm glad I never ever want to do anything like this.

Answer (score 4):

> Main question: Is T(x) the right way to force a temporary copy to be created at that point?

Yes

> Is T temp = the correct way to make sure the call to merge_QRS in the above code occurs before the call to merge_MNO but otherwise inexpensively forward the temporary from that into the first operand of merge_XYZ?

Yes

> If I used T&& temp instead does it end up holding a pointer to modified T(x) after the life of T(x)?

Yes. That's dangling reference which unfortunately the compiler won't catch.

> Is T&& the right return type (as opposed to T) for chaining a lot of these together?

To be honest, it doesn't smell good to me.

You may want to reconsider your data model to be something more standard, i.e.:

```
T merge(T x, T y)
{
  // do some merging
  return x;
}
```

Copy-elision and RVO will eliminate any redundant copies. Now you can move items in, pass copies or pass temporaries. There's only one piece of logic to maintain and your code has value-semantics... which is *always better* (TM).

Comment: I'm almost ready to believe your answer combined with the comment Arkadily made combined with one more detail (maybe obvious) is workable:  Pass and return by value.  But typically forward with `std::move`.  Trust the combination of `T::T(T&&)` and copy elision to solve cases (recursive forwarding) that I'm pretty sure copy elision alone can't solve.  I may need to test some optimized dummy code with `cout` side effects that should be elided to wrap my head around it.

Comment: But after a bit more thought, I'm too bothered by the risk of silent accidental copies.  I prefer a design in which the copy constructor is never called unless you intended it to be.  I understand that trades off against the risk of dangling references.  I'll give that more thought.

Comment: @JSF I get the disconcerting feeling that you're going against the current state of the art. In a nutshell, what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: it probably should be `return std::move( x );`

Comment: @Slava: The return value will be moved anyway, if possible.

Comment: @slava no, it should *never* be return `std::move(x)` because that defeats RVO.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** With value semantics you get:

- moves happening where possible
- No need to explictly copy arguments
- No dangling references in case of passing prvalues to the function

Consider

```
struct X 
{ 
  X() = default;
  X(int y) : a(y) {}
  X(X &&r) : a(r.a) { std::cout << "move X..."; }
  X(X const &r) : a(r.a) { std::cout << "copy X...";  }
  int a; 
};
```

with `foo`:

```
X&& foo(X &&a) { return std::move(a); }
```

and and `bar`:

```
X bar(X a) { return a; }
```

Then when executing the following Code:

```
std::cout << "foo:\n";
X x{ 55 };
std::cout << "a: ";
X && a = foo(std::move(x)); // fine
std::cout << "\nb: ";
X && b = foo(X(x)); // !! dangling RV is not prvalue but xvalue
std::cout << "\nc: ";
X c = foo(std::move(x)); // fine, copy
std::cout << "\nd: ";
X d = foo(X(x)); // fine
std::cout << "\ne: ";
X && e = foo(X{ 12 }); // !! dangling...
std::cout << "\nf: ";
X f = foo(X{ 12 }); // fine

std::cout << "\n\nbar:\n";
X y{ 55 };
std::cout << "a: ";
X && q = bar(std::move(y)); // fine
std::cout << "\nb: ";
X && r = bar(y); // no explict copy required, supported by syntax
std::cout << "\nc: ";
X s = bar(std::move(y)); // fine
std::cout << "\nd: ";
X t = bar(y); // fine, no explict copy required either
std::cout << "\ne: ";
X && u = bar(X{ 12 }); // fine
std::cout << "\nf: ";
X v = bar(X{ 12 }); // fine
std::cout << "\n";
```

we obtain

```
foo:
a:
b: copy X...
c: move X...
d: copy X...move X...
e:
f: move X...

bar :
a: move X...move X...
b: copy X...move X...
c: move X...move X...
d: copy X...move X...
e: move X...
f: move X...
```

on VS 2015 and g++ 5.2.

So the only copies made (with `bar`) are in cases b and d, which is the desired behaviour anyway but you get rid of the possibly dangling references at the cost of 1-2 moves per operation (which afaik even may be optimized out in some cases as well).